# Angular 2 - router call inside form remove query params

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a form with submit and cancel button. Upon cancel button I want to send the user to another view. I am using the router to do this, but the url has the query params and breaks.

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="submit()">
    ....form elements
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
    <button (click)="cancel()">cancel</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
cancel() {
    this.router.navigate(['../items'], { preserveQueryParams: false });
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="submit()">
    ....form elements
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
    <button <button [routerLink]="['../items', { preserveQueryParams: false }] >cancel</button>
</form>
```

Neither work and I end up with this in the URL:

> http://localhost/?query1=&query2=#/items

What is the proper way to accomplish this?